# heroku: no default language could be detected for this app

Tags: python, heroku

First time using Heroku. Trying to push. I have run the command:

`heroku create --buildpack heroku/python`

and it displayed

```
$ heroku create --buildpack heroku/python
Creating app... done, glacial-reef-7599
Setting buildpack to heroku/python... done
https://glacial-reef-7599.herokuapp.com/ | https://git.heroku.com/glacial-reef-7599.git
```

Stack trace:

```
$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 129, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (124/124), done.
Writing objects: 100% (129/129), 69.06 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 129 (delta 22), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote:  !     No default language could be detected for this app.
remote:                         HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically.
remote:                         See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to pure-badlands-9125.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/pure-badlands-9125.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/pure-badlands-9125.git'
```

I've gotta be missing something.

I have added a `requirements.txt` to my root directory. It looks like this:

```
.git
.idea
projectapp
projectname
rango
db.sqlite3
manage.py
populate_rango.py
requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't remember how I fixed this but looking at the `Date Modified` in my files after I posted this question I created two files:

`runtime.txt` (thanks **rurp**) which contains:

```
python-3.5.2
```

`Procfile` which contains:

```
web: gunicorn projectname.wsgi --log-file -
```

This is a Django project and `projectname.wsgi` leads to a `wsgi.py` located at

`projectname/wsgi.py`

This contains:

```
import os
import signal

import sys
import traceback

import time
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "projectname.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

Answer (score 22):

#### Quick Solution

1. Goto **heroku dashboard** (https://dashboard.heroku.com/)
2. **go inside app/project**
3. **click setting**
4. scroll down little bit and **click add build pack**
5. **select your desired buildpack** (in my case i have selected heroku/nodejs).

#### TLDR;

Actually what heroku does is, it tries to identify what project you are deploying by looking at files in your project, such as if your project have `package.json` file it understands it is a nodejs project, if your project have `requirements.txt` file it understands it is a python project and so on, see [this document](https://devcenter.heroku.com/start) to see to know what languages you can run on a heroku server

as you know to run a specific project such as a nodejs project in a computer node runtime must be installed in that computer otherwise you can not nodejs app in the computer, what heroku does it runs each of your app in a different container, it means in one container it is only one app is running and of course that container have installed nodejs, so if a container runs only one app it doesnt make sense to install all other runtimes in the container so container have only one runtime in my case it is nodejs. they have ofcourse other type of containers such as one type for python and that container have installed python runtime(of a specific version) so if my app gets installed in python container it will not work because my app in in nodejs. for this very reason somehow we need to identify the type of app in beginning to choose correct container type, mostly heroku automatically detect it but if it is failed to detect you have to tell explicitly either by going to their dashboard settings or through runtime file in your project, and as you may have noticed you have do this only once.

Comment: Thanks, I named my requirements file as requierments.text, so I got the error.

Comment: @VishnuVS it is requirements.txt (and not requierments.text) check the spelling and file extension both

Answer (score 11):

For future references, you must ensure that you are pushing the branch with your code to `heroku master`.

If you branched from your `master` branch and all your code is on a, say, `develop`, push that to the heroku master.

So instead of:

```
git push heroku master
```

You would do something like:

```
git push heroku develop:master
```

This question has important details on this [How to push different local Git branches to Heroku/master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971550/how-to-push-different-local-git-branches-to-heroku-master)

Answer (score 9):

When deploying using `Docker`, ensure to set the stack of the app to `container`, as shown in the [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml):

```
heroku stack:set container
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to create a runtime.txt file. On the command line, in the same folder as your requirements.txt file, enter `echo "python-3.5.1" > runtime.txt`. Of course, make sure to switch the 3.5.1 with whichever version of Python you are using.

Comment: I had the same problem, even though I have a `runtime.txt` file.

Comment: The `runtime.txt` file is optional, but recommended. It will never cause the error in the question. This error is only ever caused when no `requirements.txt`, no `setup.py`, and no `Pipfile` is found in the root directory of the project.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem even after including runtime.txt. What worked was the inclusion of the requirements.txt

Comment: Same. as soon as requirements.txt was included in the git repo and pushed, it worked fine

Comment: I have both requirments.txt and runtime.txt and it is not working... any tips?

Comment: I am facing the same issue @makewhite . Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

In my case I was in a sub git folder. When I looked at the root .git folder - the project indeed didn't had a `package.json` file - so heroku could not identify the `webpack`

Comment: Gal, did you ever get it to work with the sub folder? My git repository structure is that the main folder is a set of python projects each having its own requirements.txt

Answer (score 3):

I was running a django project and for me none of the solution above worked. So finally I gave up and went to the path thats mentioned in the error and it clearly stated that heroku needs either of the below file to detect a django project:

1. requirements.txt
2. setup.py
3. Pipfile

I than created a requirements.txt file by copying the contents of pip freeze in the root of the project and it worked correctly.

Comment: Just in case it helps someone, if you add a requirements folder to separate requirements for local and production envirionments, you will still need to add a requirements.txt in root dir, but instead of copying everything from pip freeze that file could import from production.txt like this: '-r requirements/production.txt'

Answer (score 3):

Faced this issue today and released I had named my `requirements.txt` as `requirements.txt.txt`(I literally named the file with .txt extension when it was already a text file), I also had a `runtime.txt` file with the content `python-3.8.7`.

Renaming the requirements.txt file correctly solved my issue.

I had 3 files in my root folder: code.py, requirements.txt and runtime.txt

Answer (score 3):

Adding **requirements.txt** even as a blank text file did the trick for me, and I also ensured there was **no build pack** Heroku had added.

Answer (score 2):

Heroku’s Python support extends to the latest stable release from the Python 2.x and Python 3.x series.
Today, this support extends to these specific runtimes:

- python-2.7.13
- python-3.6.1

try to change your python version in runtime.txt

Answer (score 1):

Create **Pipfile** file in root folder and add `python version` and packages required for application. [check sample file here](https://github.com/heroku/python-getting-started/blob/master/Pipfile)

```
[[source]]

url = "https://pypi.python.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true


[packages]

django = "*"
gunicorn = "*"
django-heroku = "*"


[requires]

python_version = "3.6"
```

Also check [Configuring Django Apps for Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration#creating-a-new-django-project)

Answer (score 1):

One more thing to note is to actually commit your changes to your git repo, before you can push them to Heroku.
You might have a requirements.txt setup locally, but if it's not committed to your repo, `git push heroku master` will not be able to locate it.

Answer (score 1):

If you've tried some of the above answers and the problem still persists;

Ensure you are `git` "committing" in the right directory.

For instance, if your file structure is as follow:

```
/src
    /...
    manage.py
.gitignore
Pipfile/requirements.txt
Pipfile.lock
Procfile
runtime.txt
```

Ensure you're `git` adding, committing, pushing etc. from the root directory. Since we work mostly in the `src/` or `main_app_directory/` we tend to forget to change directory back to root before committing.

Answer (score 1):

Hey guys so I have been stuck on this issue for the past two days and I found the solution to my problem. The first fix was renaming

> "requirement.txt" to "requirements.txt"
> then I removed the runtime.txt
> cleared buildpacks using heroku cli set the buildpack to python
> `heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python`

and Boom! it got uploaded an everything works now