# How do I host my discord.py bot on heroku?

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku, discord, discord.py

I am currently trying to get my discord bot on to Heroku and host it 24/7 but I am having problems.

1. I uploaded my bot to github https://github.com/zemocode/flankebot/tree/master
2. I have created the two main files I needed
3. I clicked deploy branch on Heroku and I'm getting this error.

```
 !     No default language could be detected for this app.
            HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically.
            See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
 !     Push failed
```

I have followed tutorials but everyone else has node.js and I so mine doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [heroku: no default language could be detected for this app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39873920/heroku-no-default-language-could-be-detected-for-this-app)

Comment: Nope. That is not the same thing!

Comment: Yes, they are different errors.

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing a couple of things to make this work, for the sake of everyone Googling how to host discord.py on Heroku and getting this as the top result here's a step-by-step

1. Install Git and do `git init` when inside your directory
2. (If you're using virtualenv or similar go into it and) do `pip freeze` then copy the contents you get to a file called `requirements.txt` and save it in the same repository as the bot
3. Make a file (a file of type file) [image]
   , open it with notepad and write `worker: python name_of_bot_file.py` and save within the same repository

4. Make a text file called `runtime.txt` and paste `python-3.6.5`  or whichever python version you were using to write the bot and save it in the same repository.
5. (If you're inside virtualenv get out and) open your console and write `heroku login` and input your heroku login details
6. Then do `heroku apps:create name_of_app` and `heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python`
7. Finally, do `git push heroku main` or `git push heroku branch_name:main` if you want to only push one branch

Comment: Im like not understanding. I dont have virtualenv and i have all the shit i need but it didnt work when i tried to push it

Comment: [Check this answer out and see if it helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794413/failed-to-push-some-refs-to-githeroku-com)

Comment: to anyone reading this, if you already have a heroku application you will need to add it as a remote via `heroku git:remote -a ApplicationNameHere`

Comment: The Python version used in `runtime.txt` will need to be one of the following: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#supported-runtimes

Answer (score 3):

your procfile isn't right. a web application(`web:<command>`) is for websites (which your bot isn't). the right one is `worker: python3 bot.py`.

Also, you need a `requirements.txt`. inside the file, write every module you need to download. in your case, its just `discord.py`.