# when I am trying to deploy my app on heroku. Its getting error "no default language detected"

Tags: python, django, heroku

```
git push heroku master
Counting objects: 8572, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5394/5394), done.
Writing objects: 100% (8572/8572), 15.33 MiB | 1.15 MiB/s, done.
Total 8572 (delta 2109), reused 8545 (delta 2100)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote:  !     No default language could be detected for this app.
remote:             HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically.
remote:             See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to youtooapp.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/youtooapp.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/youtooapp.git'
```

i also use a .gitignore file but when i try to push it give me this kind of error
Guys help me with that i am stuck here..

Comment: Did you look at the link? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks

Comment: yes I'm trying but it won't helping

Comment: Do you have `requirements.txt` in the repository?

Comment: yes! i have see this..

Comment: pip install -r requirements.txt
Requirement already satisfied: asgiref==3.2.3 in ./env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (3.2.3)
Requirement already satisfied: Django==3.0 in ./env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 2)) (3.0)

Comment: check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55285575/4378475