# Set the stack for an existing heroku app from heroku-18 to 'container' for a Docker image?

Tags: docker, heroku, plotly-dash

I am trying to find a way to set the stack to 'container' so I can deploy my app in a docker image rather than heroku-18. Reasons for this are complicated, but necessary.

The [Heroku Docker image setup docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml#review-apps-and-app-json) say I can do this in my `app.json` file, like so:

`"stack": "container"`

but doing this causes an error when deploying through the online interface:

```
 !     No default language could be detected for this app.
            HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically.
            See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
 !     Push failed
```

Are there other ways to set the `stack` to `container`? For e.g., according to [these docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#stack-images) it may also be possible to set this using the `Dockerfile`, but it's not clear exactly how to do this.

I know I can use the heroku CLI, but I'd prefer to set this up in my git repo as this app will be deployed to other users also.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55285575/4378475

Comment: thanks for the link! I'm trying to do this without using the GUI because I need to do this at scale for a hundred projects/apps.

Comment: Did you get your problem solved yet?

Comment: I found a workaround but this still not actually resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the stack to `container` using the command line (as an alternative to editing `app.json`), I believe

```
heroku stack:set container
```

will do the trick. You can read more about deploying containers on Heroku here (see Step 3 of Getting Started for the syntax above):

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml

Comment: Thanks! Yes I know how to do it with the CLI, but I'd like to do it using `app.json` or Dockerfile instead

Comment: exactly, i have this problem also. but don't know how to solve

Answer (score 15):

Just need to run this command

```bash
$ heroku stack:set heroku-18 --app HEROKU_APP_NAME
```

or any stack you need

```bash
# $ heroku stack:set <heroku-stack> --app HEROKU_APP_NAME
$ heroku stack:set heroku-22 --app HEROKU_APP_NAME
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this is what I was looking for!

Comment: Ahh now I remember. I thought this is what I was looking for, but I remembered I needed to do it without the CLI, but I found a workaround anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue.

The app.json specification of "stack: container" method works, when you create a "deploy to Heroku" button. (a gui way) [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-button)

`https://heroku.com/deploy?template=https://github.com/user/repo` clicking this link will work. the building will be sucessful.

But it does not work if you follow the below approach:

- create a new app from heroku dashboard
- go to the deploy tab

[image]

- connect to the github repository
  [image]
- and click deploy
  [image]